# Does SELECT account for time zone modification in WHERE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

`event_time` is stored in UTC in the database.

In trying to account for those "near the end of the month" hours so as to make sure all the results are in the **local** time, not the UTC, here is a simplified version of my code:

```
SELECT
MONTH(event_time) AS 'month'
FROM
<table1>
INNER JOIN
<table2> ON <table1>.id = <table2>.id
WHERE
<table1>.event_time BETWEEN ToDateTimeOffset(@StartDate, @Offset) AND ToDateTimeOffset(@EndDate, @Offset)
```

When using this, does `MONTH(event_time)` convert the month based on UTC or EST (which the offset sets to), or would I have to use `MONTH(ToDateTimeOffset(event_time, @Offset))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MONTH(event_time)` will take the month of the "without offset" component. But you'd be better off working out what the monthstart and monthend times are in UTC and then doing a `>=, <` query. Indexes would be used better too.

Comment: Oh, and ToDateTimeOffset just adds a timezone component. You might want `SWITCHOFFSET` instead.

Comment: A calendar table makes this much less painful.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  That's what I figured, but I appreciate the verification!